# $m$ sorts of things, $n$ things of each sort, chance that $m-r$ things selected at random all different

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A question from my probability book:

> If there be $m$ sorts of things and $n$ things of each sort, show that the chance that $m - r$ things selected at random may be all different is$$n^{m - r} {{\binom{mn + r}{r}}\over{\binom{mn+r}{m}}}.$$

Now, I was able to get$$n^{m-r} {{\binom{m}{m-r}}\over{\binom{mn}{m-r}}}.$$However, I'm not sure how to show how the two are equivalent. I tried some algebraic manipulation but it didn't go anywhere. Or maybe my expression is wrong and they're not equivalent. Any help would be well-appreciated.

Comment: You may try to give ramdom numbers for the variables to see somethings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are both equivalent.

$ \displaystyle {{\binom{mn + r}{r}}\over{\binom{mn+r}{m}}} = \frac{(mn - (m-r))! \ m!}{(mn)! \ r!}$

$ \displaystyle = \frac{m!} {r! \ (m-r)!} \cdot \frac{(mn - (m-r))! \ (m-r)!}{(mn)!}$

$ = \displaystyle \frac{{m \choose m-r}} { {mn \choose m-r}}$